# Powershell Loop though specific json files from multiple folders and use that json file to push into Loop

Tags: powershell

```
$tenantID = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId
$mg = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/" + $tenantID

foreach($subfolder in Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\AzurePolicies -Depth 2 -Recurse){
    Write-Host "Subfolder is " $subfolder
    foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $subfolder -File *.json -Recurse){
        foreach($policy in $file){
            $displayname = (Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).properties.displayName
            Write-Host "Display name is" $displayname
            $policyname = (Get-Content $policy -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).properties.name
            Write-Host "Policy name is" $policyname
            foreach ($item in $policy) {
                function DefinePolicies {
                    New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name $policyname -DisplayName $displayname -Policy $policy   -ManagementGroupName $tenantID
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
                }
                DefinePolicies
                function AssignPolicies {
                    $policy = Get-AzPolicyDefinition -Name $policyname  -ManagementGroupName $tenantID
                    New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name $policyname -PolicyDefinition $policy -Scope $mg
                     Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
                }
                AssignPolicies
            }   
            }
    }
}
```

My Files are organized as Azurepolicies/Keyvaults/Somepolicy/azurepolicy.json

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The loop doesn't end and there and it repeats, sorry newbie trying here so can you help me out

Comment: I might be able to help you if you [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71860762/edit) and explain: what are you trying to do, how are you expecting the current code to work, and what the _actual_ behavior is. Please be mindful that I can't see your screen or read your mind - you have to tell us what's wrong if we are to help you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your ```$displayname = (Get-Content $file -Raw …``` can move up a line - you’re currently reading the file contents for every ```$policy```, but you only need to read it once per ```$file```. Also, you’re re-defining the ```DefinePolicies``` and ```AssignPolicies``` on every loop which is unnecessary - just in-line the code instead (but rename ```$policy``` inside ```AssignPolicies```).

Comment: Also, add some of your output that shows where it repeats…